# Orchard AutoFac Conflicts

Tags: orchardcms, autofac, orchardcms-1.8

I am currently working on a project in Orchard. We are looking to wrap up an existing .NET MVC Web application within an Orchard Module. Currently, we are having issues with AutoFac.

The original site was built using AutoFac 3.5, however the latest stable version of Orchard is still running on 3.0. The application requires features introduced in 3.3. If I install 3.0 into the module, the features do not work, if I have 3.5 in the module, it produces a conflict. 
Can anybody suggest a way of handling this conflict? Or, is it safe to upgrade AutoFac 3.0 in Orchard and if so how should I perform this without breaking it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest, **Orchard 1.9** should be released soon™ and it already has dependency on latest stable **Autofac 3.5.2**. If you don't want to wait you can grab latest repository from GitHub 
https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/tree/1.9-int

It's perfectly stable in my opinion and I find released **1.8.1** to be much more buggy :D.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the web.config file **runtime** Node from **Existing Module** (Lucene or Markdown or like) and add the runtime node on conflicts Module Web.Config file. After Compile then clear the Conflict